# populate jsp combobox using another jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jsp-tags

> i want to populate combobox in my jsp using another jsp. i already try many thing but those doesn't work for me
>
> jsp design code

```
<form id="obj" class="login-form" action="PickUpInvertProcess.jsp">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="td1">Client:</td>
<td class="td2"><select tabindex="1"name="clientname"> 
<c :forEach var="name" items="${obj.name}">
<option value="${name}">${name}</option>
</c :forEach>
</select>
</td>
```

> using script in jsp to load comboBox value

```
<body>
<%!
public Set<String> loadDropDown() throws SQLException {
Set<String> CLIENTDATA = new HashSet<String>();
Dbcon dbc = new Dbcon();
Connection con = dbc.ConnDb();
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        String Query = "here query";
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(Query);
        while(rs.next()){
            CLIENTDATA.add(rs.getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally{
        dbc.disconnect(null, st, rs, null);
    }
    return CLIENTDATA;
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider loading the list in the `@Controller` class and passing it as a model attribute.
See [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-and-list-example/) a simple example.

Then assuming the passed attribute is called `names`, the combobox can be filled the following way:

```
<select id="id_names" name="name">
    <c:forEach items="${names}" var="name">
        <option>${name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: thanku, for your reply......but i want to populate combo box using another jsp...if you have any idea about that then, please tell me

Comment: If you use the new jsp only for a concrete object from the model then simply use jsp:include directive.

However, if you want to use it for arbitrary lists, then you will need to make a [custom tag](http://www.journaldev.com/2099/jsp-custom-tags-example-tutorial), because you can only pass string arguments to jsp files and not objects.

Answer (score 0):

The following will iterate a collection of objects which exist is some scope  i.e which have been placed into some scope by a previous process:

```
<c:forEach var="name" items="${clientDataList}">
```

You need then to put the results of your query into a valid scope. Using Request scope you can do this:

```
<%!
Set<String> CLIENTDATA = new HashSet<String>();
Dbcon dbc = new Dbcon();
Connection con = dbc.ConnDb();
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        String Query = "here query";
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(Query);
        while(rs.next()){
            CLIENTDATA.add(rs.getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally{
        dbc.disconnect(null, st, rs, null);
    }

    request.setAttribute("clientDataList", CLIENTDATA);
%>
```

**However you should note that using Java code in JSP files went out of fashion in around 2002 and read this:
[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1)**